# numpy - Computing "element-wise" difference between two arrays along first axis

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

Suppose I have two arrays `A` and `B` with dimensions `(n1,m1,m2)` and `(n2,m1,m2)`, respectively. I want to compute the matrix `C` with dimensions `(n1,n2)` such that `C[i,j] = sum((A[i,:,:] - B[j,:,:])^2)`. Here is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array(range(1,13)).reshape(3,2,2)
B = np.array(range(1,9)).reshape(2,2,2)
C = np.zeros(shape=(A.shape[0], B.shape[0]) )
for i in range(A.shape[0]):
    for j in range(B.shape[0]):
        C[i,j] = np.sum(np.square(A[i,:,:] - B[j,:,:]))
C
```

What is the most efficient way to do this? In R I would use a vectorized approach, such as `outer`. Is there a similar method for Python?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`scipy's cdist`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html), which is pretty efficient for such calculations after `reshaping` the input arrays to `2D`, like so -

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist

C = cdist(A.reshape(A.shape[0],-1),B.reshape(B.shape[0],-1),'sqeuclidean')
```

Now, the above approach must be memory efficient and thus a better one when working with large datasizes. For small input arrays, one can also use [`np.einsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) and leverage [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html), like so -

```
diffs = A[:,None]-B
C = np.einsum('ijkl,ijkl->ij',diffs,diffs)
```